# How to take a screenshot in cordova/phonegap application

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to take a screenshot in my cordova application using [this](http://plugreg.com/plugin/gitawego/cordova-screenshot) plugin, but an error is occuring. I don't really know what the error is, as I am testing it on my android smartphone and the app just blocks. In the browser, the same is happening with this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined`, where 'save' comes from this code:

```
navigator.screenshot.save(function(error,res){
      if(error){
        console.error(error);
      }else{
        console.log('ok',res.filePath);
      }
    });
```

P.S.:  Also tried `navigator.plugin.screenshot...`, `navigator.plugins.screenshot`,
        `window.screenshot`, `window.plugin.screenshot` and `window.plugins.screenshot`

P.S.2: I checked if plugin is installed with `cordova plugins` in cordova CLI and everything is ok, plugin           exists in plugins folder and is for cordova version>=3.0.0 and mine is newer

But of course, the browser isn't really loading the plugin, because this error also occurs there: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:23273/www/cordova_plugins.json`. No screenshot is taken, checked on my smartphone.

Comment: did you created object of Screenshot where you using navigator.screenshot.save ?

Comment: I think not, how and where do I do that? I am really new to phonegap and don't know where to make changes to use plugins, this is the first plugin I ever tried on phonegap

Comment: and did you added platform in pluging.xml file ?

Comment: yes, android platform is already added for me in plugin.xml. Check the github repo, I haven't changed anything. Can you tell me how and where to create that object of Screenshot. It is obviously not as simple as var screenshot = new Screenshot();

Comment: P.S.: I used a try catch block and on android the error is the same : cannot call method save of undefined

Comment: try to alert a msg in save function in screenshot.js .. is it showing alert msg ?

Comment: nope, nothing happens. The error is the one I wrote above on this line of code: navigator.screenshot.save(function(error,res){

Comment: which cordova version you are using ? i noted this line in plugin.xml..on github..                                                                                   <js-module src="www/Screenshot.js" name="screenshot">
        <merges target="navigator.screenshot" />
    </js-module>

Comment: Cordova version: 3.5.0-0.2.6; Yes, what about this line in plugin.xml? Should I change something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58165/discussion-between-dhwanik-gandhi-and-user3127242).

Comment: Whenever you are ready ;) Sorry for the long delay, have loads of work today ;/

Comment: Just writing this comment to push question up a little maybe. Not sure how it works here. I would start a bounty, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation for a good bounty ;/ If anybody has some ideas, please share...I am still banging my head with this ;(

Comment: You need to do **cordova plugin add https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot.git** and then **cordova prepare android**. Are you already performing these 2 steps?

Comment: Not cordova prepare android. Really sorry if I am taking too much of your time, I am really new to phonegap. Which one of the scripts do I need to include also? I have no js/libs folder in platform android...do I need to copy screenshot.js to my lib folder in www?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using Worklight and was going through the same problem. My solution was to change de code of the file Screenshot.js to:

```
var formats = ['png','jpg'];

function Screenshot() {
}

Screenshot.prototype.save = function (callback,format,quality, filename) {
    format = (format || 'png').toLowerCase();
    filename = filename || 'screenshot_'+Math.round((+(new Date()) + Math.random()));
    if(formats.indexOf(format) === -1){
        return callback && callback(new Error('invalid format '+format));
    }
    quality = typeof(quality) !== 'number'?100:quality;
    cordova.exec(function(res){
        callback && callback(null,res);
    }, function(error){
        callback && callback(error);
    }, "Screenshot", "saveScreenshot", [format, quality, filename]);
};

Screenshot.install = function () {
      if (!window.plugins) {
        window.plugins = {};
      }

      window.plugins.screenshot = new Screenshot();
      return window.plugins.screenshot;
    };

cordova.addConstructor(Screenshot.install);
```

This way I can make the call with the following code:

```
window.plugins.screenshot.save(function(error,res){
          if(error){
            alert(error);
          }else{
            alert('ok',res.filePath); //should be path/to/myScreenshot.jpg
          }
        },'jpg',50,'myScreenShot');
```

This worked perfectly on my Android smartphone.

I also added in res / xml / config.xml file:

```
<feature name="Screenshot">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.screenshot.Screenshot"/>
</feature>
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And added the java class in the following package: org.apache.cordova.screenshot.Screenshot

All these configurations have the information in the plugin.xml file of the plugin

Comment: I am sorry, which java class have you added? Your solution looks promising, testing it now :)

Comment: The class of the plugin [cordova-screenshot-master](https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot/blob/master/src/android/Screenshot.java)

Comment: Still giving me the same error, cannot read property save of undefined... :( I am sure your solution works, but I can't get it to. Could you upload all the phonegap files of your project to github, please? It will be a lot easier for me, maybe I am doing something wrong, hope angular.js is not the reason ;(.

Anyways, I accept your answer now and when I get it to run when I get back home this evening, I will give you the bounty too ;). Thanks!

Comment: I'm also using AngularJS in my app. You have added the js in your html page Screenshot (<script src="js/libs/screenShot/Screenshot.js"></script>)? Is running in an application server?

Comment: Ok, I copied screenshot.js to my www/lib folder, where I put all my scripts, and linked it in index.html. Now it's kind of better, code is being executed to cordova.exec... in screenshot.js and then nothing... I put it in a try catch, no error there...just cordova.exec is not returning anything... weird ;/

Answer (score 1):

do you load your project in localhost ? why do you have this kind of file:

`http://localhost:23273/www/cordova_plugins.json.` ?

you are trying to simulate the cordova project with "cordova serve 23273" ? you can't use any plugin with "cordova serve".

you should have file:/// as protocol...

Comment: I am testing it on my smartphone too, with a try cach block the error alerted is "TypeError: Cannot call method 'save' of undefined". But huge thanks for your time and effort to help me. I appreciate it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, unfortunately I cannot give a real answer to this question, as I did many things. The final one was to update my cordova.js file to the latest version, which actually solved my problem, but every comment and answer assisted a lot.

I want to thank both @Talysson de Castro and @Darktalker for helping me out! :)